# Your project location contains whitespace. (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I am just moved from Eclipse to Android Studio for android application development. I am getting the following warning at the time of creating projects

**Your project location contains whitespace. This can cause problem on some plateform and is not recommended**

I wanted to know how to resolve this and is it serious or not?

Comment: Well fairly obviously, you can resolve it by *not* having whitespace in your project location. The "is it serious" is hard to tell, partly as the warning is deliberately somewhat vague. I would try to fix it by changing the project location though...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The white space refers to any name in the location that has a space.

In the example:

c:/users/MyDocuments

the location does not have white space. However, the location

c:/users/My Documents

has white space. Remove the spaces from the folder names in your location or use underscore to remove the white space from your location.

Comment: It seems like Android Studio still lives in 80's and that is not acceptable...  When the OS doesn't care about space who is Android Studio to decide what characters it can contain in the path names?  Isn't that ridiculous to have separate folders just for Android Studio???

Answer (score 5):

This will not cause any serious issue. You can continue your regular development. But as you have recently switched to the new environment, so I think it will be easy to move your directory now. If you face any import or export related issue later (when moving the directory would have become harder), then it will be really a pain for you.

**How you can solve this issue:**
Just change the directory of your workspace to (where there wouldn't be any white space).

**For example:** *c:/users/documents*

Answer (score 3):

I took the UNIX approach, and created a symbolic link to where the directory should be located. On Windows, from a command window:

```
mklink /j C:\android-sdk C:\"Program Files"\Android\android-sdk
```

Answer (score 1):

welll this problem also i am getting

your are browsing that location contain white space mean

for ex my /c/ documents

it solution is u have to remove space between tham

solution my/c/documents