# Your project location contains whitespace.

Tags: android, android-studio, setup-project

As my project's location contains whitespace, I'm getting the warning described below:

**Your project location contains whitespace. This can cause problems on some other platforms and is not recommended.**

What kind of platforms it corresponds to or what kind of problems I can betide.

Comment: For example: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5036

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but why 3 down votes??

Comment: You get down votes because there a few bunch of people who do not have any other work that annoying others with trying to understand the question and trying to help.  that is what it is and not because they know too much...  that is my opinion..

Comment: Respect to you Vincy

Comment: [this should answer your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29469403/your-project-location-contains-whitespace-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

whitespace is not preferable for project location .
If it is used more than a certain limit it will malfunction or even leads to crash the IDE...

Comment: I've used project locations with spaces without any problem, can you reference your claim?

Comment: I have faced problem when i was exporting signed apk and it kept crashing then in last i changed the path and it works perfectly ...

Comment: Which OS are you using? Windows?

Comment: linux mint  16 cinnamon

Comment: Never had this issue in Ubuntu and I work daily with Android. Good to know though, thanks.

Comment: In windows, Android Studio doesn't let you have your project inside the "My Document" folder because as per Android Studio it is invalid.  But my question is, if the IDE is designed for windows then who in the world Android Studio is to decide which characters we can have in the folder names?  isn't it ridiculous to have separate folders just to make Android Studio happy??